# TensorFlow - Invalid argument: Reshape:0 is both fed and fetched

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Is there a way to both feed and fetch the same variable in Tensorflow? If not, why is this not allowed?

I'm getting this error:

```
StatusNotOK: Invalid argument: Reshape:0 is both fed and fetched.
```

Answer (score 7):

You can not have a Tensor that is both fed and fetched. The work-around is to add "tf.identity" op and fetch that

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
a_copy = tf.identity(a)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(a_copy, feed_dict={a:1})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that my error was occurring because I was running on a deprecated version of TensorFlow. I'm still interested to hear about how variables can appear in both feed and fetch though!