# why does this error "input_2_1:0 is both fed and fetched" happen?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to show the output of intermediate layers in my network and I used the below code:

```
from keras import models
layer_outputs = [layer.output for layer in w_extraction.layers[:102]] 
activation_model = models.Model(inputs=w_extraction.input, outputs=layer_outputs)
activations = activation_model.predict([x_test[8000:8001],wt_expand])
```

but it produces this error. I do not know why it produces this error! coudl you please help me with this issue

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       activations = activation_model.predict([x_test[8000:8001],wt_expand])
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 1169, in predict
>       steps=steps)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py",
>   line 294, in predict_loop
>       batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 2715, in **call**
>       return self._call(inputs)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 2671, in _call
>       session)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 2623, in _make_callable
>       callable_fn = session._make_callable_from_options(callable_opts)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1471, in _make_callable_from_options
>       return BaseSession._Callable(self, callable_options)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1425, in **init**
>       session._session, options_ptr, status)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py",
>   line 528, in **exit**
>       c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
>
> InvalidArgumentError: input_2_1:0 is both fed and fetched.

my complete code is here:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, GaussianNoise,Dropout,BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Conv2D, AtrousConv2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras import backend as K
from keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import keras as Kr
from keras.optimizers import SGD,RMSprop,Adam
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import keract
from matplotlib import pyplot
from keras import optimizers
from keras import regularizers

from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Lambda;
#-----------------building w train---------------------------------------------
w_expand=np.zeros((49999,28,28),dtype='float32')
wv_expand=np.zeros((9999,28,28),dtype='float32')
wt_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(49999,4,4))
wt_random=wt_random.astype(np.float32)
wv_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(9999,4,4))
wv_random=wv_random.astype(np.float32)
w_expand[:,:4,:4]=wt_random
wv_expand[:,:4,:4]=wv_random
x,y,z=w_expand.shape
w_expand=w_expand.reshape((x,y,z,1))
x,y,z=wv_expand.shape
wv_expand=wv_expand.reshape((x,y,z,1))

#-----------------building w test---------------------------------------------
w_test = np.random.randint(2,size=(1,4,4))
w_test=w_test.astype(np.float32)
wt_expand=np.zeros((1,28,28),dtype='float32')
wt_expand[:,0:4,0:4]=w_test
wt_expand=wt_expand.reshape((1,28,28,1))

#-----------------------encoder------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
wtm=Input((28,28,1))
image = Input((28, 28, 1))
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(image)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(conv1)
conv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(conv2)
BN=BatchNormalization()(conv3)
encoded =  Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='encoded_I',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BN)


add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1])
encoded_merged = add_const([encoded,wtm])

#-----------------------decoder------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
deconv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(encoded_merged)
deconv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(deconv1)
deconv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='convl3d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(deconv2)
deconv4 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='convl4d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(deconv3)
BNd=BatchNormalization()(deconv3)
#DrO2=Dropout(0.25,name='DrO2')(BNd)

decoded = Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='decoder_output',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BNd) 
#model=Model(inputs=image,outputs=decoded)

model=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=decoded)

decoded_noise = GaussianNoise(0.5)(decoded)

#----------------------w extraction------------------------------------
convw1 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl1w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(decoded_noise)
convw2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw1)
convw3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl3w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw2)
convw4 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl4w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw3)
convw5 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl5w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw4)
convw6 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl6w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw5)
pred_w = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='reconstructed_W',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw6)  
w_extraction=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=[decoded,pred_w])

#----------------------training the model--------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------------Data preparation----------------------------------------

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
x_validation=x_train[1:10000,:,:]
x_train=x_train[10001:60000,:,:]
#
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_validation = x_validation.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_validation = np.reshape(x_validation, (len(x_validation), 28, 28, 1))

#---------------------compile and train the model------------------------------
w_extraction.compile(optimizer='adam', loss={'decoder_output':'mse','reconstructed_W':'binary_crossentropy'}, loss_weights={'decoder_output': 0.45, 'reconstructed_W': 1.0},metrics=['mae'])
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=20)
#rlrp = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=20, min_delta=1E-4, verbose=1)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model_5x5F_dil_Los751.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
history=w_extraction.fit([x_train,w_expand], [x_train,w_expand],
          epochs=200,
          batch_size=16, 
          validation_data=([x_validation,wv_expand], [x_validation,wv_expand]),
          callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='E:concatnatenetwork', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False),es,mc])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't both feed and fetch a placeholder (i.e. the underlying Tensor of an `Input` layer). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39307302/2099607) for more information. Therefore, you must exclude the input Tensors of `w_extraction` model from the outputs of `activation_model`. One way to do this is to filter them based on layer name:

```
layer_outputs = [layer.output for layer in w_extraction.layers[:102] if not layer.name.startswith('input')]
```

Comment: I used the answer in https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer for showing the intermediate layer output and it works for me. Thank you.