# tensorflow-serving gives me a "is fed and fetched" error for the same model that works from the command line

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

When I run a prediction with `saved_model_cli` it executes properly, but the same inputs give me an error when I try to run it through tensorflow-serving.

It tells me that an item is being both fed and fetched (because it is in the inputs and the outputs) but it works fine from the command line. Does anybody know why it works with one and not the other or how to go about fixing it?

Comment: did you find an answer? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks similar to the issue mentioned in the below link :

[Placeholder_2:0 is both fed and fetched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307108/placeholder-20-is-both-fed-and-fetched)

Please refer to this and see if it resolves your issue. If not, please share the code snippet to further debug the issue.